# Passing function by reference problem with typing

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm trying to numerically calculate some tricky integrals with GSL, and I'd like the implementation to separate out the integrands from the GSL implementation to make my code more readable (and debuggable). These are the functions that actually evaluates my models, what's in them isn't important:

```
double Integrand1(double *k, size_t dim, void *params) {
    double result = k[0]*k[1]*k[2];
    return result;
}      
double Integrand2(double *k, size_t dim, void *params) {
    double result = k[0]-k[1]-k[2];
    return result;
}
```

And this is where I'm running into trouble, trying to abstract the calls to GSL. Note the type constraints for the `gsl_monte_function G`:

```
void EvalIntegral(double &func, int_info &params,double *xl,double *xu,size_t dim,
                              double &result,double &error){
    const gsl_rng_type *T;
    gsl_rng *r;

    gsl_monte_function G;
    G.f = &func;  //This must be double (*)(double *,size_t,void *)
    G.dim = dim;  //This must be size_t
    G.params = &params; //This is a struct holding some variables

    size_t calls = 5e5;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);

    gsl_monte_vegas_state *s = gsl_monte_vegas_alloc(dim);
    gsl_monte_vegas_integrate(&G,xl,xu,dim,1e5,r,s, &result,&error);

    gsl_monte_vegas_free (s);
    gsl_rng_free (r);  
}
```

I set up the above function to reduce some clutter in another function:

```
void Evaluate(double x, double y){
    int_info params;
    params.x = x; 
    params.y = y;

    //Lower limits to the variables 
    double xl[3] = {0.,-100.,0.};
    //Upper limits to the variables
    double xu[3] = {100.,100.,1.};

    double result1, result2, error1, error2;

    EvalIntegral(&Integrand1,&params,xl,xu,3,&result1,&error1);
    EvalIntegral(&Integrand2,&params,xl,xu,3,&result2,&error2);
}
```

When I compile, though, it seems to be refusing my passing the integrand functions:

```
error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double (*)(double*, size_t, void*)’ {aka ‘double (*)(double*, long unsigned int, void*)’} in assignment
 G.f = &func;
        ^~~~
```

I'm a little confused, all of this works when I copy the contents of `EvalIntegral` into `Evaluate` twice and replace `func` with `Integrand1` and `Integrand2`. How can I convince the compiler that `func` is a function with the right prototype?

Comment: Why is it `double &func`? You need a function type.

Comment: Your answer is in the error message. Instead of `double &func`, you need `double (*func)(double*, size_t, void*)`.

Comment: And also note that the first parameter of `IntegrandX` should be `double*`, not `int*`.

Comment: @Evg Thanks, that's just a typo from trying to translate this as a minimum example. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler gives you the answer: instead of `double&` you need a function pointer type:

```
void EvalIntegral(double (*func)(double*, std::size_t, void*), ...)
```

Comment: *pushes scientist glasses back* I didn't know you could DO that! That change, coupled with untying some of the dependency hell I created for myself, seems to have done the trick. Thanks to you and @scohe001 !